# Contact form PHP issues

Tags: php, forms, contacts

I have no experience in PHP, because of this I have no idea what to even search for. I'm making a contact form for an union in Norway.

```
<?php

$first_name = $_POST{'first_name'};
$last_name = $_POST{'last_name'};
$mail = $_POST{'mail'};
$message = $_POST{'message'};
$to = "email@domain.com";
$subject = "New Message";
mail ($to, $subject, $message, "From: " . $first_name . $last_name);
echo "Your Message has been sent";

?>
```

The code is working just fine. But I want an additional function. I want the e-mail and name from the sender to appear in the content of the email.

Something like this:

> From: Bryan Smith
>   E-mail: Bryan@smith.com
>   "Message message message message message message message message message message message message "

Right now only the message is showing up in the message in the mail.

Answer (score 0):

You use `concatentation` in order to join strings together. Let's have a look:

```
$message = "FROM: $first_name $last_name<br/>E-mail: $to<br/><br/>$_POST['message'];
```

Make sure this appears after you declare `$to = "email@domain.com"`

Comment: in this case need html header

Answer (score 0):

You can easily concatenate the name and email in your message.

```
$message = 'From'.$_POST['first_name'].' '.$_POST['last_name'];
$message .= 'Email'.$_POST['email'];
$message .= $_POST['message'];
```

Add html tags accordingly. **Happy Coding**

Answer (score 0):

```
    $to='thomasafure@gmail.com';
    $from = $_POST['mail'];
    $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
    $second_name = $_POST['lats_name]
    $subject="message from : ".$name;
    $message = "message from  :  ".$from."\r\n";
    $message.=$_POST['message];
    $message=wordwrap($message,70,"<br>");
    $message=str_replace("\n.","\n..",$message);
    $headers='From: example@sxamle.com';
    $mail=mail($to, $subject, $message , $headers);
    if ($mail==true)
        echo "message sent";
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're trying to achieve is something like this:

```
Bryan Smith <bryan@smith.com>
```

Try to make your header like this

```
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: Bryan Smith <bryan@smith.com>' . "\r\n";
```

Read more [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php/).

Answer (score 0):

You need to concatenate your message along with `From` and `E-mail`.

**Example:**

```
$first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
$last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
$mail = $_POST['mail'];
$message = "From: ".$first_name. " ".$last_name. "\r\n"; // ADD THIS
$message .= "E-mail: ".$mail. "\r\n"; // ADD THIS
$message .= '"'.$_POST['message'].'"';

$to = "email@domain.com";
$subject = "New Message";
if(mail($to, $subject, $message, "From: " . $first_name . $last_name))
  echo "Your Message has been sent";
```

I am also adding `mail()` inside the `if condition`, if message sent than message should be displayed.